# Below code write for filter data and I want to modify it to filter by dates and time (11-3-2023 , 8-55-24)

Tags: vue.js

Below code is written for filter data and I want to modify it to filter by date and time (11-3-2023, 8-55-24)

```
const filterTableData = {

    searchData(sourceData, fields, keyword) {
        var outputArray = [];
        sourceData.forEach(function(row){
            let pushed = false
            fields.forEach(function(fieldName){
                if(String(row[fieldName]).match(RegExp(keyword, "i")) && !pushed){
                    outputArray.push(row)
                    pushed = true
                }
            });
        });

        return outputArray
    }
}
export {filterTableData}
```

I want to modify the above code to filter by date

Comment: What is preventing you from modifying the code?